# Format code to be more readable when counting a filtered list

Tags: python

I have following code:

```py
fruits = content.find_all("fruit")
matching_fruits = [fruit for fruit in fruits
    if fruit.has_info('name') and fruit.has_info('source') and fruit.info['source'].endswith('primary')]

return len(matching_fruits)
```

How can I either reduce the code, or make it more readable? I am interested in making it look good in IDE and be more easy to read.

In Kotlin, I might do this like:

```kotlin
1) content.findAll("fruit").filter(...).filter(...).size
2) content.findAll("fruit").count(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it shorter this way:

```
fruits = content.find_all("fruit")
return sum(fruit.has_info('name') and 
        fruit.has_info('source') and
        fruit.info['source'].endswith('primary')
        for fruit in fruits)
```

This works because `False` and `True` can also be interpreted as numbers `0` and `1` by Python.

Generally: Ensure that the expression evaluates to a boolean value (which is the case here). Boolean operators `and` and `or` actually evaluate to one of the operands, therefore all operands should evaluate to a boolean.

Comment: thank you, definitely better. I like how just reading sum gives you context of the entire line. Nice detail about how boolean can be counted as well.

Comment: @rupinderjeet The authoritative style guide [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) has no final answer but actually recommends to move binary operators like the "and" to the beginning of the next line unlike I did it here.

Comment: yes, I found this style guide (and I am currently reading it). I agree, with style guide, it gets easier for other devs to read my code.

Comment: There's one caveat I'd like to add: this works correctly because each piece of logic actually return `True` or `False`, but if `and` does not specifically return those values: it returns the value of the last operand if they're all truthy, or the value of first falsy operand. E.g., `True and 3` is `3`, and `[] and True` is `[]`. So `sum()` will not always do what you want if the operands of `and` don't all specifically return `True` and `False`.

Comment: @joanis Thank you, I added a paragraph about this.